# Images do not display with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack

My tree view:

```
- app
  - App.js
- assets
  - Linux.png
- render-web.js
- webpack.config.js
```

My config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?https://localhost:9000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './render-web'
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],

  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    https: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: false,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          ast: false,
          babelrc: false,
          comments: false,
          minified: true,
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['syntax-flow', 'react-hot-loader/babel'],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules\/react-native/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'url-loader?limit=9999999',
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My entry file:

```
/* globals document */
import {AppContainer} from 'react-hot-loader';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app/App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('reactors');

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <App />
  </AppContainer>,
  rootElement
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./app/App', () => {
    const NextApp = require('./app/App').default;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
         <NextApp />
      </AppContainer>,
      rootElement
    );
  });
}
```

Then from `app/App.js`:

```
import LinuxIcon from '../assets/Linux.png';

<img src={LinuxIcon} />
```

The path is correct (if I change it, webpack complains it does not exist).

It generates a base64 image:

`data:image/png;base64,77+...too long to paste`

But it just displays a blank square (no image). *What am I doing wrong?* Thanks!

BTW using:

- file-loader@0.10.0
- url-loader@0.5.7
- webpack@2.2.1
- webpack-dev-server@2.3.0

**PS** I've tried to move the `assets` directory into `App` as I've seen suggested but with no luck.

Comment: I think you may have to set the same `publicPath` property on webpack-dev-server configuration. So that your deployment env can respect those publicPath settings.

Comment: Adding `publicPath: '/assets/'` to `webDev` does not work either - plus then hot reload and bundling altogether does not work anymore :( @SeanLarkin

Comment: Might want to console.log(LinuxIcon) to make sure the value is what you are expecting. I'm not sure how the import syntax treats an image as dep.